# How do I create a non mutually exclusive categorical variable?

Tags: stata, logistic-regression, categorical-data

In Stata I am analyzing a study looking at pre-existing conditions that participants may have had that affect whether they experience side effects after vaccination.

For each participant, there are three binary variables that denote whether the participant had that condition (0: does not have, 1: does have), namely hypertension: 0/1, asthma: 0/1, diabetes: 0/1.

However, these categories are not mutually exclusive as the participant can have any combination of conditions: (no pre-existing conditions, only hypertension, only asthma, only diabetes, hypertension and asthma, hypertension and diabetes, asthma and diabetes, hypertension and asthma and diabetes).

I would like to perform a regression analysis to determine the risk of developing side effects given exposure to pre-existing conditions and to create a variable denoting the different combinations.

I would like to get the risk ratios for the following table:

| Type of pre-existing condition | With side effects | no side effects | risk ratio |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| None | 455 | 316 | ref |
| Hypertension | 51 | 28 |  |
| Asthma | 42 | 26 |  |
| Diabetes | 17 | 7 |  |

Does anyone havecode that would help in creating a new categorical variable to help with this regression analysis?

I've tried using the following code, but because the categories are not mutually exclusive, the values assigned overwrite each other. `new_var` denotes the new variable created denoting the pre-existing conditions.

```
generate new_var = 0 
replace new_var = 1 if hypertension == 1 
replace new_var = 2 if asthma == 1
replace new_var = 3 if diabetes == 1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 8 possible combinations of preexisting conditions, and one approach is to add the variables like this, then manually label them:

```
generate new_var = hypertension * 4 + asthma * 2 + diabetes
label define preexisting 0 none 1 diabetes 2 asthma 3 "asthma and diabetes" 4 hypertension 5 "hypertension and asthma" 6 "hypertension and diabetes" 7 "hypertension, asthma and diabetes"
label values new_var preexisting
```

If you have additional preexisting condition variables, multiply them by 8, 16, 32 and so on to get unique values for every combination.

Another approach is to use [interactions in the regression](https://www.stata.com/manuals/u26.pdf).

```
regress outcome hypertension##asthma##diabetes
```

Comment: Thank you for your response Stuart! I've created this new variable but the issue is that when I perform the regression analysis, i get outcomes for each combination of pre-existing condition. When I would really like to find the risk ratio for each pre-existing condition whether or not the others are present as well (to complete the table shown above). I hope this makes sense.

Comment: @Becky Yes but then you don't need to 'create a variable denoting the different combinations'. If you are not interested in interactions, then you probably just need to include each condition as an independent variable (predictor) in your regression. (You might need to seek stats advice e.g. from https://stats.stackexchange.com/ to clarify exactly what analysis is appropriate, before figuring out how to program it in Stata.)

Comment: @Becky The goal of assessing the influence of each condition separately is unfortunately unrealistic for precisely the reason you're asking the question: conditions are often combined.

Answer (score 1):

This is as much statistical as Stata-oriented, but there is a Stata dimension, so here goes.

@Stuart has indicated some ways of getting composite variables in Stata, but as no doubt he would emphasise too, watch out that the numeric coding is arbitrary and not to be taken literally.

Other methods of creating composite variables were discussed in [this paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800700407) and that advice remains valid.

That said, I suspect most researchers would **not** use a composite variable here at all, but would use as predictors the three indicators you already have and their interactions. That is the only serious and supported method to get estimates of effect size together with appropriate tests.